# Show Order ID in Dynamics CRM Order Look up instead of Order Name

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

In Dynamics CRM 2016 (on-prem), I've custom child entity `Parties`that have a look of type `order`. Currently it is working properly and it is showing `order name` but I want it to show `Order ID`.

I tried to resolve by creating my own view, adding order id field only and making it default view for the look up but it don't meet my requirements.

Comment: Are you referring to what you see on the form after you search for and select a specific order? Or are you referring to the columns you see when you open a lookup dialog and search for the Order you want?

Comment: I want the lookup field to populate order id instead of order name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by the lookup view for Orders. The first three fields in the lookup view are shown when selecting records from the lookup field.

You cannot change the position of (or remove) the Name field from the lookup view. That still leaves you with two additional fields to be shown, one of which could be the Order ID.

I know no supported ways around this (except creating a workflow to copy the Order ID to the Name field and adding a custom name field instead, if you really insist).

Answer (score 0):

Changing what appears on the form after you make a selection in a lookup field is not possible, unfortunately.  The primary attribute is **always** what gets displayed after a user specifies a lookup value (which, for the Order entity, is the Name attribute).  As Henrik's answer mentions, people commonly get around this by copying the value they want to see into the primary attribute using a workflow or a plugin.